# How to create an ad space within a list - flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, ads

I have this app which am about to create with flutter and i want to be able to sell **ad space** within it where users can place their ads and other people can view it when scrolling like facebook or instagram ads which randomly just shows.
So what i want to know is how to add an ad space within a list which is gotten from the database
[image]

Like from the image above i want the ad space to be place within a list of post (maybe ListView) and then still continue showing the post after inserting the ad space within it. Is there a way to do this in flutter.

NB: If you need more explanation or you still don't understand please tell me.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @Andrej haven't started am just trying to know what i need in the app before starting so as not to have any problem after starting

Comment: Well, the first solution I came up with (might not be the best one) is to use a `ListView.separated` and build the ads in it's `separatorBuilder` function.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to fetch only 4-5 items from the DB, store them in a List and add to this list your ad, and you repeat this process every time the user has scroll at the end of the List.

Comment: So does that mean i have to keep fetching data from the database every time the user scrolls through 4-5 post and adding the ad at the end. wouldn't that annoy some users with low internet network

Comment: It could, but this is the most convenient way to do it, Instagram, and Facebook timelines use the same principle.